# other.transform.SetParent messes up with scale of my player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i was working on to make my moving platform stable for my player. 
I used `void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)`' inside platform container script and used '`player.transform.SetParent(plankTranform);`'
But setting player transform to be child of platform transform messes up with scale of player.

My best guess is that platform's scale property is being  transferred into player's transform.scale. Is there way to just set `tranform.position` of platform as parent of player's `transform.position`?

Using `player.transform.SetParent(plankTranform);` automatically sets tranform 3 properties i.e (position,scale,rotation) to child object. I dnt really want to deal with scale and rotation in this case

```
public class BrickMoveVErtical : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector3 positionOne;
    public Vector3 positiontwo;
    public Vector3 nextposition;
    public Transform plankTranform;

    /*Empty object is already made on unity editor and its parent of 
     platform(Plank) and other  
   empty object "pointB". Point "B" is already mapped on editor and platform 
     is set to go from  its original pos to point B */

    public Transform positionBTransform;
    public float speed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        positionOne = plankTranform.localPosition;
        positiontwo = positionBTransform.localPosition;
        nextposition = positiontwo;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        move();
            }
    private void move() {
   plankTranform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(plankTranform.localPosition,nextposition,Time.deltaTime*speed);
        if(Vector3.Distance(plankTranform.localPosition,nextposition)<0.1)
        { changeMovementPlank(); }
    }
    void changeMovementPlank() {
        nextposition = nextposition != positionOne ? positionOne : positiontwo;
    }   

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {  if(other.gameObject.tag=="Player")
        {
            other.transform.SetParent(plankTranform);


        }

    }   
    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        other.transform.SetParent(null);
    }                  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use `SetParent(parent, true);`

> **worldPositionStays**
>
> If true, the parent-relative position, scale and rotation are modified such that the object keeps the same world space position, rotation and scale as before.

Comment: @Dracos18s So i used `other.transform.SetParent(plankTranform,true);` instead of `other.transform.SetParent(plankTranform);` but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: @EslaBaeny Pass `false` to it

Comment: @Programmer passing false to it makes the game crash

Answer (score 0):

You could try avoiding the scale problem by making your own artificial parent script similar to this.
You set a parent object and every frame it just moves and rotates the transform based on where the fake parent moves in the past frame.
If you're doing a 2D game you just remove the rotation stuff and keep the position stuff.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FakeChild : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform fakeParent;

    private Vector3 lastPos;
    private Quaternion lastRot;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (fakeParent == null)
            return;

        //gets change in rotation of fake parent
        var rotChange = fakeParent.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(lastRot);

        //change object rotation
        transform.Rotate(rotChange.eulerAngles.y * Vector3.up);

        // gets the vector of the distance from parent to object and rotate it by change in parent rotation
        transform.position = rotChange * (transform.position - lastPos) + lastPos;

        //moves how much the fake parent moves
        transform.position += fakeParent.position - lastPos;

        lastRot = fakeParent.rotation;
        lastPos = fakeParent.position;
    }

    public void SetFakeParent(Transform parent)
    {
        if(parent == null)
        {
            fakeParent = null;
            return;
        }

        fakeParent = parent;
        lastRot = fakeParent.rotation;
        lastPos = fakeParent.position;
    }
}
```